# MemCache-repcached compile error

Tags: php, linux, caching, gcc, operating-system

I'm trying to install [repcached - memcached which implemented multi master asynchronous replication feature](http://sourceforge.net/projects/repcached/) in it's version memcached-1.2.8-repcached-2.2.1 [<sup>*Download*</sup>](http://sourceforge.net/projects/repcached/files/latest/download?source=files).

I have the following error after running `make`:

> make  all-recursive
>
> make[1](http://sourceforge.net/projects/repcached/files/latest/download?source=files): Entering directory `/usr/local/src/pro/memcached-1.2.8-repcached-2.2.1'
>
> Making all in doc
>
> make[2]: Entering directory `/usr/local/src/pro/memcached-1.2.8-repcached-2.2.1/doc'
>
> make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
>
> make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/src/pro/memcached-1.2.8-repcached-2.2.1/doc'
>
> make[2]: Entering directory `/usr/local/src/pro/memcached-1.2.8-repcached-2.2.1'
>
> gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -DNDEBUG   -g -O2 -MT memcached-memcached.o -MD -MP -MF 
>   .d> eps/memcached-memcached.Tpo -c -o memcached-memcached.o `test -f 'memcached.c' || echo 
>   './'`memcached.c
>
> memcached.c: In function ‘add_iov’:
>
> memcached.c:697: error: ‘IOV_MAX’ undeclared (first use in this function)
>
> memcached.c:697: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
>
> memcached.c:697: error: for each function it appears in.)
>
> make[2]: *** [memcached-memcached.o] Error 1
>
> make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/src/pro/memcached-1.2.8-repcached-2.2.1'
>
> make[1](http://sourceforge.net/projects/repcached/files/latest/download?source=files): *** [all-recursive] Error 1
>
> make[1](http://sourceforge.net/projects/repcached/files/latest/download?source=files): Leaving directory `/usr/local/src/pro/memcached-1.2.8-repcached-2.2.1'
>
> make: *** [all] Error 2

OS : Centos5.7 64bit

gcc-4.1.2-51.el5

gcc-c++-4.1.2-51.el5

libgcc-4.1.2-51.el5

Note : Memcached and memcache extension for php are already installed

> root@server[~]# memcached -h
>
> memcached 1.4.5

php ext http://pecl.php.net/get/memcache-2.2.6.tgz

Comment: Are you using memcached 1.2.8 ? To check: `$ memcached -h`

Comment: @greut I'm using memcached 1.4.5

Comment: repcached seems to be for memcached 1.2.8 or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to compile with -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=500, so `IOV_MAX` is defined.

Comment: I added `#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 500` into **memcached.h** and i still have the same error after `make` command

Comment: Still no `IOV_MAX`? Is `limits.h` included?

Comment: Yup, I have #include <limits.h> in memcached.c but i noticed that there is not entry inside /usr/include/limits.h for IOV `grep IOX /usr/include/limits.h` blank output.

Comment: `/usr/include/stdio_lim.h` has **define IOV_MAX 1024** and it included  also into memcached.h file.

Comment: Then it beats me why `IOV_MAX` is undeclared... Contact the author ;)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, and both this answer and your (unanswered) question in ServerFault were at the top of Google.

Managed to work out the problem at the end, posted at ServerFault:
https://serverfault.com/questions/353987/memcache-repcached-complie-error/375998#375998